# Apply CSS font-weight in digit?

Tags: css, text, fonts

Font-weight does not apply value in digit.

**Open Sans** is the only one font found CSS apply `font-weight:500` or `font-weight:300` wondering about this weird behaviour.

I researched got only this : http://bit.ly/1c2FClx  any answer?

Comment: Not all google fonts have those styles. Next to each font is a button **see all styles** for those fonts that have multiple font weights, like _open sans_.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer, Do you know any other font which apply font-weight in digit? Can you provide resource if any?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How it works css font-weight values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207331/how-it-works-css-font-weight-values)

Answer (score 1):

In response to your question in your comment under your initial question, where you ask:

> Do you know any other font which apply font-weight in digit?

The linked article says:

> The keyword value `normal` maps to the numeric value `400` and the value
>   `bold` maps to `700`.

The CSS keywords are proxies for the common font weights `400` and `700`. Thus, even when you use a keyword you are still referring to a numerical value but that number is implicit rather than explicit. You must explicitly declare a number such as `300` or `500` because CSS offers no keyword corresponding to those values.

All of which is to say, in response to your question, that *all* font weights are numerical. What numerical values you can declare for font-weight depend on the weights available for a given font. As the linked article demonstrates, not all weights 100 - 900 are available for every font and declaring a numerical weight that is unavailable will:

> simply display the logically closest weight.

Answer (score 0):

Your link basically explains it better than anyone can explain. basically if you are using a custom font that has the particular font weight, then it will be rendered or else the default is rendered.