# CSS font-weight numbers: how do they work?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm trying to use font-weight to adjust how bold the font is. From what I understand, value 500 is the normal font weight, and value 700 is the default font weight for bold.

However, when I put 599, it did not change the font-weight at all. But when I put 600, it jump to the default font weight of bold. Same results from value 600-900. Then when you go over 900, the font weight reverts back to the normal font weight. Why is this happening?

```css
#fontStyle {
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-weight: 599;
}
```

```html
<div id="fontStyle"> fontStyle </div>
```

Comment: Use only hundreds like 600 or 500 (100 to 900)

Comment: @vlzvl Makes me wonder what the two extra zeros are for.

Comment: Looks like a similar question was asked previously: [How it works css font-weight values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207331/how-it-works-css-font-weight-values?rq=1)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The details of how numeric values are mapped to font weights are covered [in the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-boldness) which states:

> The values '100' to '900' form an ordered sequence, where each number
>   indicates a weight that is at least as dark as its predecessor. The
>   keyword 'normal' is synonymous with '400', and 'bold' is synonymous
>   with '700'. Keywords other than 'normal' and 'bold' have been shown to
>   be often confused with font names and a numerical scale was therefore
>   chosen for the 9-value list.

'599' is not a valid value for the `font-weight` property

Comment: Just keep in mind a Variable fonts, that can contain any weight between standard hundreds. I see a date of a question, but times have changed now and we can't ignore this possibilities.

Answer (score 15):

Default font weight is 400, and fonts work in multiples of 100. 300 is light (if your font supports it), 400 is regular, 600 is semibold and 700 is bold. You can't use the numbers in between.

Answer (score 1):

font-weight works from 100 to 900 in increments of 100. Normal weight is 400. Bold is 700.

599 is not a recognized weight since it isn't an increment of 100. Anything over 900 is not recognized either.

So you should be using font-weight: 600 for semi bold or font-weight:700 for bold.

This link helps explain https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight

Answer (score 1):

Well you've used 599, you can only use numbers 100, 200, 300 etc.. 
so `font-weight: 600` would work